# How to check whether Java Script is enabled or not in client side from servlet?

Tags: javascript, java

Actually I have done it by hidden field concept and using cookies. But one problem is with these methods. If user or client manually add query string to url and cookies in browser then our website will accept that yes javascript is enabled. Then please tell me other method.
This is my JSP page 
 -

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
       <html>
       <head>
       <title>Registration</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Validation.js"></script>  
       </head>
       <body>
       <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/RegisterUser" method="post" onsubmit="return javascript:validate();">
       UserName : <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Enter User Name">
       Email : <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Id">
       Password : <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
       Retype-Password : <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" placeholder="Enter Password Again">  
       <input type="submit" value="Register">
       <input type="hidden" name="jsStatus" id="jsStatus">
       </form>
       </body>
       </html>
```

And I have Java Script as

```
function validate() {
    var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var repassword = document.getElementById("repassword").value;
    var jsStatus = document.getElementById("jsStatus").value = "enabled";
    return true;
}
```

And my servlet :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/RegisterUser")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//      general settings
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");

//      Reading request parameters
        if( request.getParameter("jsStatus").equalsIgnoreCase("enabled") ){
            pw.println("<font>Java Script Is Enabled</font>");
        }
        else{
            pw.println("<font>Java Script Is Disabled</font>");
        }
    }
}
```

Question : Now if i will click on the register button it will go nicely and display JavaScript is enabled if enabled otherwise JavaScript is disabled.
 But if i will give request to this servlet manually by extending query string as jsStatus=enabled then also my servlet will display javascript is enabled then my logic in servlet will also execute.
How to solve to this problem?

Comment: Why does your server depend on JavaScript being enabled in the user's browser? I'd just check whether it is enabled or not and if not warn the user that the site won't work as expected.

Comment: you have done what? Question is far too vague. Please narrow down your specific problem and reference it to your code

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display "JavaScript is disabled", you could do the following in your HTML:

```
<noscript>JavaScript is disabled</noscript>
```

If there's actually stuff you want to do on the back-end when JavaScript is disabled, please drop a comment and I'll update the answer.

It looks like you're trying to validate user input on the client-side though. If that's the case, don't do it because client-side JavaScript can be modified and thereby sabotaging your validation code. User input should always be validated server-side (both client and serverside is okay as well, client-side would then only be for nice error messages and reducing the amount of requests to your server).

Comment: @Vivek Kurmi Please accept my answer if it answers your question or leave a comment if it doesn't.

Comment: Actually I don' want to perform validation twice. I want that if javascript is disabled then only i want to perform validation on server side. But appending query string fails my logic on server side as i writen in my servlet code. So what to do? Please tell me.

Comment: @Vivek Kurmi I do not onderstand what your question is. If you want to do validation on clientside if JavaScript is enabled and if JavaScript is disabled on server side, don't do that, always check on at least serverside.